# How to "crop" offscreen <div> in iOS safari (on actual device)?

Tags: ios, ipad, safari, scroll, css

I have some offscreen divs (to be moved in later with transform) on a full width page, but iOS safari (on the actual device) just don't crop it, instead it extends the scrollable area.

You can see this setup (300x300 box nudged -100 to the right) in action (browse on an iPad, desktop just works fine): http://www.eppz.eu/responsive/offscreen.html

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<title>Off screen divs</title>
<style type="text/css">

    body
    {
        margin: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        overflow:hidden; /* Can't crop with this :( */

        background: url('tile.png');
    }

    #offScreen
    {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        margin-left: auto; /* To the right */

        position: relative;
        right: -100px; /* Nudge offscreen */

        background: url('300.png');
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="offScreen"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I've inspected it on an iPad, computed style of body seems fine (width is 768px):

```
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: 
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
background-image: url(http://eppz.eu/responsive/tile.png);
background-origin: padding-box;
display: block;
height: 300px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
width: 768px;
```

How to prevent safari from horizontal scrolling here? I'd prefer CSS only solutions, I have not much intention to "litter" markup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhy safari needs another wrapper introduced right after *body*, then everything works as expected.
Something like:

```
#view
{
    position:relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: I was pulling my hair out over this

Comment: @Brenwell I did the same at that time between question and answer. :D